# Meteor, register modal helper (bootboxjs)

Tags: javascript, meteor, bootbox

I am trying to create an helper that creates modals using [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) but I am having trouble with it. 
I would like it to look like :

```
  {{ #modal }}
    Whatever I want
    {{ > MaybeEvenAnotherTemplate }}
  {{ /modal }}
```

I have tried this :

```
 <!-- html -->
 <template name="_modalContent">
   {{ > UI.contentBlock }}
 </template>


// js
Template.registerHelper('modal', function() {
    opts = {};
    opts.title = "Sometitle";
    opts.message = "<div class='bootbox-content'></div>";                                                                                                                                    
    bootbox.dialog(opts);                                                                                                                                                                    
    Blaze.render(Template._modalContent, $('.bootbox-content')[0]); 

   return Template._modalContent; // I get the errors with or without a return  
});
```

It is not working. I know the part inside the helper works in standalone (like in the javascript console, it works when rendering other classic templates like forms...), but coupled with the "#modal" helper with block, I just get:

- `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property '__isTemplateWith' of null`
- `Uncaught Error: Expected template or null, found: undefined`

with no file indicating where the problem is coming from.

I guess I could just remove bootbox.js and be pretty fine, but I would love to make this work, does anybody have an idea why it is failing ?

Thanks.

Comment: {{#modal}} isnt helper, {{modal}} is

Comment: What about https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#new-pattern-for-defining-custom-block-helpers was my main doc trying to do this and it says otherwise, is it outdated?

Comment: To be honest, in 6 months I work with meteor I never really came across that kind of helpers. I can't help you further since I open bootbox only via some click in js

Comment: I have made such a helper, but did not have any success using bootbox though. Just used bootstrap markup instead. If ever it can help someone, the code is here : https://gist.github.com/gabriel-dehan/520bc63dd14a7f069074

I made a short readme to help.